# How to get a running function's output as an event in Python

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the example posted below...

On my machine `calcIt()` function takes about 5 seconds to complete.
The same `calcIt()` function is called from inside of MyClass's callCalcIt() method.
Using `while` loop MyClass is "watching" for `calcIt()` function to finish.

Question: A `while` loop inside of calcIt() method prints out `'...running'` only once. Honestly I was expecting to see at least 'an infinite loop' type of behavior where `'...running'` would be printed thousand times per second. Observing a fact the `while` loop executes `a print '...running'` line only once makes me believe `while` loop watches very 'loosely' for `calcIt()`'s progress. If so, what other (other than `while` loop) approach should be used to make sure you get what you want: an instant feedback from calcIt() function?

```
def calcIt():
    a=True
    while a:
        for i in range(25000000):
            pass
        a=False
    return True

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()

    def callCalcIt(self):
        b=True
        while b:
            result=calcIt()
            print '...running'
            if result: b=False

print 0    
calcIt()
print 1

c=MyClass()
c.callCalcIt()
print 2
```

## EDITED LATER:

Posting a revised code with an implementation of solution suggested by Ebarr:

```
import threading

updateMe=[]

def calcIt():
    a=True
    while a:
        for y in range(3):
            for i in range(15000000):
                pass
            updateMe.append(1)
        a=False
    return True

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()

    def callCalcIt(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=calcIt)   
        thread.start()
        print '\n...thread started'
        while thread.is_alive():
            if len(updateMe)==1: print '...stage 1'
            if len(updateMe)==2: print '...stage 2'
            if len(updateMe)==3: print '...stage 3'

    def printUpdate(self):
        print 'updateMe=', len(updateMe)


c=MyClass()
c.callCalcIt()
```

Comment: After `result=calcIt()` `result` is `True`, so `b` becomes `False`, so the loop exits.

Comment: I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding how a single threaded application behaves.  Function calls block until they return something.

Comment: Ok. What would be your answer then?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get what you mean. But if you're on single thread and running synchronous code, one function shall return/yield before the next one starts. In this example, it seems the loop only run once, because the control variable (say, `a`) is set to `False`. So you only see 'running' once

Comment: I see now. I thought while loops 'loop' or iterate through them self with a speed of light: again and again: till False is encountered. I need a solution for this. What could be used to 'listen' for the calcIt() continuously? Post an example please.

Comment: You can't get instant feedback from `calcit`, because `calcit` takes ages to complete. It doesn't have any useful feedback to provide until it's done with its 25 million iteration loop. Loops take time.

Comment: In other words, you want to trace the progress of the function?

Comment: Yes, I need to keep eye on what function is doing. This particular calcIt() function returns/sends data only once. But in real-life a called function could send 'some messages' to the function that is listening... you know what i mean.

Comment: Functions don't work like that. If you imagine a little guy in your computer following the instructions you've written for him in your program, a function call means "pause what you're doing and follow the instructions in this other function, then keep going from here when you're done with that". It doesn't send another little guy off to execute the function call while the first guy carries on.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would make a difference but I am looking for a solution where mutiprocessing is involved heavily. In the example I posted things are quite simple and straightforward. It is all good to know anyway. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: @Sputnix I would recommend posting your edited code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as they can give you some pointers on structure etc. that don't belong on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were expecting to happen, but the explanation is very simple. You are running a single threaded code. This means that all of the above will be executed in serial, so there will be no concurrency between the two while loops in your code.

What you appear to be asking is how to thread your code such that you can check the progress of a running function. If that is the case, you can turn `calcIt` into a thread.

```
import threading

class CalcIt(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(25000000):
            pass
```

You would then change `callCalcIt` to:

```
def callCalcIt(self): 
    thread = CalcIt()     
    thread.start()
    while thread.is_alive():
        print '...running'
```

Alternatively, you can make it simpler:

```
import threading

def calcIt():
    for i in range(25000000):
        pass

def callCalcIt():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=calcIt)
    thread.start()
    while thread.is_alive():
        print '...running'

callCalcIt()
```

Comment: If I replace `thread = CalcIt()` to lowercase `thread = calcIt()` and run what you've posted I get an `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'start'` But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: After an edit it does it beautifully! Ponts up from me! Thanks~ ;)

Comment: @Sputnix I changed the case to reflex the fact that `CalcIt` had become a class in the first case. See PEP8 (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

I can come up with two ways of doing that, but both require some modification to the `calcIt` function.

Method 1, callbacks:

```
def calc_it(callback):
    r = 25000000
    for x in xrange(r+1):
        if not (x % 1000):
            callback(x, r)  # report every 1000 ticks

class Monitor(object):
    def print_status(self, x, r):
        print "Done {0} out of {1}".format(x, r)

    def call(self):
        calc_it(self.print_status)
```

Method 2, generator:

```
def calc_it():
    r = 25000000
    for x in xrange(r+1):
        if not (x % 1000):  # report every 1000 ticks
            yield x, r

class Monitor(object):
    def call(self):
        for x, r in calc_it():
            print "Done {0} out of {1}".format(x, r)
```

(A side note: in neither case `Monitor` has to be a class, that's just for consistency with the original code.)

Comment: Wow! Now I even have a choice! Thanks a lot! Great info!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but you could possibly use [my newly written generator state machine thingie](https://github.com/highfestiva/generatorstate). Like so:

```
from generatorstate import State

def calcIt():
    while True:
        for i in range(25000000):
            pass
        yield

tick = State(calcIt)
print 0
tick()
print 1
tick()
print 2
```

I've added a couple of examples, sneak a peek at those if you think it might be a fit.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am trying to keep it all stock. But I will keep it in mind there is always another `thingie` out there!